# Selecting empty mysql datetime fields

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is there a better way to select empty datetime fields than this?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `datetime_field` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Better in what way? That query does everything you ask of it and, provided there's an index on `datetime_field`, it's as fast as it's going to get.

If you're worried about the query looking "ugly", don't be. Its intent is quite clear.

The only possible improvement you could consider is to use NULLs for these zero-date/time rows, in which case your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `datetime_field` IS NULL
```

That's what I'd do with a standards-compliant DBMS. My understanding is that MySQL **may** represent true NULL datetime fields in this horrific manner, in which case I guess the `IS NULL` may not work.

Comment: Just came across case where "IS NOT NULL" didn't work. Comparing to the "ugly" string might be better. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html

Answer (score 31):

`SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_field) = 0`

I like this code because it not only catches "zero dates" (e.g. '0000-00-00 00:00:00') is also catches "zeroes in dates" (e.g. '2010-01-00 00:00:00')

Comment: I agree, it's also just nice to have something that looks visually different, though a row of zeroes does look obvious enough I imagine.

Comment: This code however fails for dates before the unix time stamp era, 1971, so it's not usable except for current dates. Dates of birth, that is, for example.

Answer (score 21):

Provided your date/datetime column is NOT NULL you can just use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `datetime_field` IS NULL
```

MySQL will select columns that equal '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for you.

*Note*: If you do:

```
SELECT `datetime_field` IS NULL
```

MySQL will return 0 (false), but this statement will be true when used as part of the WHERE clause.

### From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)

> For DATE and DATETIME columns that are declared as NOT NULL, you can find the special date '0000-00-00' by using a statement like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE date_column IS NULL
> ```
>
> This is needed to get some ODBC applications to work because ODBC does not support a '0000-00-00' date value.

Answer (score 9):

Or you can simply do :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `datetime_field` = 0
```

Comment: Works with != 0 as well, not like with NOT NULL.

Answer (score 6):

I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_field`) = 0
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL > 10 on ubuntu 20.04 and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('0000-00-00 00:00:00') returns null instead of zero! so, i used null in my query and it works well.

Answer (score 4):

As another option, I have seen:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE YEAR(`datetime_field`)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_field`) IS NULL
```

Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP, it handles null, empty, and any invalid datetime strings.

As @Lizardx mentioned earlier in this page, UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not support very old or future dates. In such cases, one can omit the function and its benefits!

The valid range of argument values for UNIX_TIMESTAMP is from 1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000 UTC to 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 UTC.

Comment: The only time that `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` doesn't return an unsigned number is when `NULL` is the passed in value.  In which case, why not just check that it is `NULL`?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp  Please defend your snippet as a good coding technique by editing some explanation into your answer.

Comment: What is the result when the datetime value is `1969-12-30 23:59:59`?

Answer (score -3):

Let me put out a disclaimer, I'm not sure what this will do. But it would be really cool if it worked.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime = DATESUB(NOW(),NOW());
```